# Where the Impresspages page content is stored?

Tags: database, impresspages

Here I am referencing to the content inserted in the controls. For instance Texts, etc. I couldn't figure it out anywhere. No database entry, no files in the folders storing the website content. I am working in version 4.5.2. It is weird that the publisher hasn't documented this so it is an open source initiative! Anybody knows where is it stored?

Answer (score 1):

Content data is stored in the database. "ip_widget" table "data" field.